# Kruskal wallis test for small dataset in R

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test, sign-test

I'm trying to test if there are systematic differences in a balanced `data.frame` composed by 25 observations of 3 variables:

```
'data.frame':   25 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ sum: num  0 5228 7715 7715 7780 ...
 $ time: int  2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 ...
 $ categories: Factor w/ 5 levels "I","II",..: 5 5 5 5 5 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

- $sum: a response numeric variabile representing surfaces extension, expressed in m²;
- $time: a numeric variabile relative to temporal interval, with 5 years (2012-2016);
- $categories: a nominal variable of 5 levels, I-V.

The question is:

Did sum values systematic change over time (from 2012 to 2015) in each level of categories?

I level: 2012 m² vs 2013 m² vs 2014 m² vs 2015 m² vs 2016 m²

II level: 2012 m² vs 2013 m² vs 2014 m² vs 2015 m² vs 2016 m²

III level: ...

IV level: ...

V level: ...

Because of the lack of normality assumption i'm performing kruskal wallis rank sum  test in R (`kruskal.test`) for each level of $categories: (5 test).

When i run the 5 analysis i get the same pvalues for every single test (>0.05), even if sum values are different.

Am i performing kruskal wallis test correctly?

Can i accept the null hipotesis and adfirm that there are no significant differences in values among groups?

Are there any more suitable tests to perform? (`cor` test, `wilcox.test` or `SIGN.test`)

Thank you so much.